# IF OR Google Spreadsheets Formula Problem

Tags: google-sheets

I'm getting an error back for this formula. I've tried with commas, without space, short formula and I still can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the formula that I'm using:

> =IF(OR(C3 = "Jenna"; C3 = "Maureen"; C3 = "Kelvin"; C3 = "Kevin"; C3 = "Rafael"; C3 = "Sean"; C3 = "Wing"; C3 = "Ariel"); "ACCTG"; =IF(OR(C3
>   = "Randy"; C3 = "Becca"); "AP"; =IF(OR(C3 = "Jack"; C3 = "Candace"); "PAYROLL"; =IF(OR(C3 = "Mike"; C3 = "Amy"; C3 = "Brett"; C3 = "Noah";
>   C3 = "Erick"; C3 = "Derrick"); "PM"; =IF(OR(C3 = "Daniel"; C3 =
>   "Deep"; C3 = "Nicole"); "SRTGY"; "ERRR!")))))

I'm trying to get a text output based on a text value.

Comment: If you share a doc with us, then Eddy or somebody else can perhaps evaluate the situation and find a more efficient solution to your problem.

Comment: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All works, just replaced `=IF` with `IF`, (apart from the 1st one).

> =IF(OR(C3 = "Jenna"; C3 = "Maureen"; C3 = "Kelvin"; C3 = "Kevin"; C3 = "Rafael"; C3 = "Sean"; C3 = "Wing"; C3 = "Ariel"); "ACCTG"; IF(OR(C3 = "Randy"; C3 = "Becca"); "AP"; IF(OR(C3 = "Jack"; C3 = "Candace"); "PAYROLL"; IF(OR(C3 = "Mike"; C3 = "Amy"; C3 = "Brett"; C3 = "Noah"; C3 = "Erick"; C3 = "Derrick"); "PM"; IF(OR(C3 = "Daniel"; C3 = "Deep"; C3 = "Nicole"); "SRTGY"; "ERRR!")))))

I find it best to start with something short then join the statements, after I have things working.

I wish they would auto indent long formulas, to make them easy to fix/edit.

Comment: looks like =VLOOKUP() would be a better solution.