# multiple IF statements with between number ranges alternative

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

How to efectively deal with multiple IF-statements and with multiple "between number" ranges 
 in Google Sheets' spreadsheet (e.g. **C** column based on **B** column)

[image: 9]
with a rule set as follows:

```
01-10
11-20
21-50
51-100
101-150
151-200
201-300
301-500
501-800
801-1000
1001-1222
1223-1568
1569-1800
etc...
```

---

## `IF()`

```
=IF(AND(B2>=1;    B2<10);     "01-10"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=11;   B2<21);     "11-20"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=21;   B2<51);     "21-50"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=51;   B2<101);    "51-100";
 IF(AND(B2>=101;  B2<151);   "101-150"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=151;  B2<201);   "151-200"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=201;  B2<301);   "201-300";
 IF(AND(B2>=301;  B2<501);   "301-500"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=501;  B2<801);   "501-800"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=801;  B2<1001);  "801-1000";
 IF(AND(B2>=1001; B2<1223); "1001-1222"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=1223; B2<1569); "1223-1568"; 
 IF(AND(B2>=1569; B2<1800); "1569-1800";)))))))))))))
```

- disadvantages of a standard `IF` statement nestings are:

  - long syntax
  - per single row dependency
  - tricky post-editing
  - tricky array formula support

---

## `IFS()`

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(
 IFS(B2:B>=1569; "1569-1800";
     B2:B>=1223; "1223-1568";
     B2:B>=1001; "1001-1222"; 
     B2:B>=801;   "801-1000";
     B2:B>=501;   "501-800";
     B2:B>=301;   "301-500";
     B2:B>=201;   "201-300";
     B2:B>=151;   "151-200";
     B2:B>=101;   "101-150";
     B2:B>=51;     "51-100";
     B2:B>=21;     "21-50";
     B2:B>=11;     "11-20";
     B2:B>=1;      "01-10"));)
```

- disadvantages of `IFS` statement are:

  - long syntax
  - tricky post-editing
  - reverse order logic dependency

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `VLOOKUP()`

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B;
 {QUERY(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(
  REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet2!A2:A; "(\d+)"))); ); "SELECT Col1")\
  QUERY(Sheet2!A2:A; "SELECT A")}; 2)); )
```

[image: 9]

where **Sheet2** consists a list:

[image: 9]

---

---

#### US syntax:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,
 {QUERY(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(
  REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet2!A2:A, "(\d+)"))), ), "SELECT Col1"),
  QUERY(Sheet2!A2:A, "SELECT A")}, 2)), )
```

Answer (score 4):

## `CHOOSE()` with `MATCH()`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(B2:B,
{1, 11, 21, 51, 101, 151, 201, 301, 501, 801, 1001, 1223, 1569}),
"01-10",
"11-20",
"21-50",
"51-100",
"101-150",
"151-200",
"201-300",
"301-500",
"501-800",
"801-1000",
"1001-1222",
"1223-1568",
"1569-1800"), ))
```

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662726/

Comment: This works wonderfully well.

Answer (score 2):

## standalone single cell solution using `VLOOKUP()`

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {{1,      "01-10"  };
                                     {11,     "11-20"  };
                                     {21,     "21-50"  };
                                     {51,     "51-100" };
                                     {101,   "101-150" };
                                     {151,   "151-200" };
                                     {201,   "201-300" };
                                     {301,   "301-500" };
                                     {501,   "501-800" };
                                     {801,   "801-1000"};
                                     {1001, "1001-1222"};
                                     {1223, "1223-1568"};
                                     {1569, "1569-1800"}}, 2)), )
```

[image: *]

Answer (score 2):

## `ARRAYFORMULA()` with `IF()`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 IF((B2:B>=1)    * (B2:B<11),     "01-10", 
 IF((B2:B>=11)   * (B2:B<21),     "11-20", 
 IF((B2:B>=21)   * (B2:B<51),     "21-50", 
 IF((B2:B>=51)   * (B2:B<101),    "51-100",
 IF((B2:B>=101)  * (B2:B<151),   "101-150", 
 IF((B2:B>=151)  * (B2:B<201),   "151-200", 
 IF((B2:B>=201)  * (B2:B<301),   "201-300",
 IF((B2:B>=301)  * (B2:B<501),   "301-500", 
 IF((B2:B>=501)  * (B2:B<801),   "501-800", 
 IF((B2:B>=801)  * (B2:B<1001),  "801-1000",
 IF((B2:B>=1001) * (B2:B<1223), "1001-1222", 
 IF((B2:B>=1223) * (B2:B<1569), "1223-1568", 
 IF((B2:B>=1569) * (B2:B<1800), "1569-1800", ))))))))))))), ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`=query()` is useful for this.

1. Split the "rule set" into lower and upper limits, and create a named range to contain all three resulting columns (here named "rule_set"):
   [image: named range of number ranges, and lower and upper limits thereof]

To find which range the number belongs, C2 contains the following:

`=query(rule_set,"select G where I>=" & B2 & " limit 1")`

- rule_set is the named range we are querying
- Column G of the named range contains the number range to return
- Column I of the named range is the upper limit
- B2 is the value we're trying to match to a number range
- "limit 1" restricts the result set to one item only. Given these are ascending values, the lowest matching value is returned.

[image: Values for which we are trying to find a matching a range]

To avoid having to repeat this formula in every row containing values you're matching to a range, you can embed this in the byrow() Lamda helper function.