# Subtract different percentage based on quantity range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to be able to provide a different percentage discount based on the quantity purchased.
The percentage should be based on a range, so for example:

- QTY > 0 && <= 5, discount = 5%
- QTY > 5 && <= 10, discount = 10%
- QTY > 10 && <= 15, discount = 15%

What would be the best way to achieve this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A30:A), 
 B30:B-(B30:B*(IF(A30:A>=15, 15%, 
               IF(A30:A>=10, 10%, 
               IF(A30:A>=5,   5%, ))))), ))
```

[image: 0]

- more alternatives here: **[https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471[2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471)**