# ArrayFormula combined with ISBLANK

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Kind of new here. Tried to look for a similar answer but not quite getting it to work.

I made a formula - it worked.
I turned it into an array formula - it worked.

But it was returning 0's in the column where the reference cell was blank. 
I looked up `ISBLANK` and that seems like the right answer... 
I combined them - not broken, but not working. (so ArrayFormula is still giving the correct answer, but 0's are all still there)

Any ideas?
I've worked my way to this point - made a sample file 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19h9OOShLHYV8qDhTl3wrWSPfnxpsXBI3kvN8BXYUOFw/edit?usp=sharing

I get the I needed to put the `IF(ISBLANK)` _before the ArrayFormula, and if you look at my example it works..until you fill in cell B4, then all the zeros show up. 
I'm pretty sure I'm making a pretty basic mistake at this point. thanks in advance - if you don't look at the file, here's the formula:

```
 =if(isblank(B:B),"",ArrayFormula(IF(B4:B>=900,B4:B*0.2,IF(B4:B>=400,B4:B*0.15,IF(B4:B>=200,B4:B*0.1,IF(B4:B<=199,B4:B*0,FALSE))))))
```

Comment: btw, more alternatives to your formula here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(O4:O),
 IF(O4:O>=900, O4:O*0.2,
 IF(O4:O>=400, O4:O*0.15,
 IF(O4:O>=200, O4:O*0.1,
 IF(O4:O<=199, O4:O*0, )))), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the alternative answer, but I am trying to learn what mistake I made with the ISBLANK formula.

Comment: @FinneganBrubeck did you see the 2nd picture? your mistake is that you use different range sizes in ISBLANK and ArrayFormula

Comment: ahh... the my problem was I didn't understand the second picture!
This does make sense, thank you! solved.

Comment: @FinneganBrubeck also ArrayFormula should be always the first eg. before anything else

Comment: hey user0 - I just wanted to say thanks again. I know this didn't get a lot of views, but now that I actually understand.. I actually learned how it works - and that was my goal all along. Thanks for coming back to explain - my problem is solved, I feel like I'm writing cleaner formulas, my formatting is better.. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a range to ISBLANK just as you did *isblank(B:B)* because if you want to pass a range, it actually does need the same ARRAYFORMULA function.

If you want to make it work, you can do it this way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B4:B),"",IF(B4:B>=900,B4:B*0.2,IF(B4:B>=400,B4:B*0.15,IF(B4:B>=200,B4:B*0.1,IF(B4:B<=199,B4:B*0,FALSE))))))
```

Check it out [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_b_JbaTj_qN0F-LWGadV725GWXw4hbM3R5ZTqKM9GMc/edit?usp=sharing), copied from your sample file.

And a picture for you to be worth a thousand words:

[image]

Also as a side note, instead of multiple IF statements it might be a better idea to use IFS, will look much cleaner and easier to follow and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Please try, in C4:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B4:B),B4:B*(choose(match(B4:B,{0,200,400,900}),0,0.1,0.15,0.2)),""))
```